# My form's validate() is not working

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

NOTHING IS WORKING! I added onSubmit = "validate()" to my register button in the form, and I made the function and the alert if the fields are left empty. But NOTHING IS WORKING!
No alerts no errors in console. No hope!

```html
<head>
    <title>WHAT THE TECH!</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function validate() {
        let fullname = document.getElemenyByname("full_name").value;
        let email = document.getElemenyById("email").value;
        let pass = document.getElemenyById("password").value;
        let add = document.getElemenyById("address").value;
        if (fullname == "" || fullname.length == 0) {
            alert("Enter Full Name");
            document.getElemenyById("full_name").focus;
            return false;
        } else if (email == "" || email.length == 0) {
            alert("Enter Email Address!");
            document.getElemenyById("email").focus;
            return false;
        }
    }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="mainwrap">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="SignUp">
                <div class="Formup">
                    <div class="title">New here? Register!</div>
                    <form name="register">
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Full Name: </td>
                                <td><input type="text" id="full_name">
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Email: </td>
                                <td><input type="text" id="email">
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Password: </td>
                                <td><input type="password" id="password">
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Country: </td>
                                <td>
                                    <select>
                                        <option value="U.A.E">U.A.E</option>
                                        <option value="K.S.A">K.S.A</option>
                                        <option value="Qatar">Qatar</option>
                                    </select>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Gender: </td>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" checked> Male<br>
                                    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Female<br>
                                    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="other"> Other
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Address: </td>
                                <td><input type="text" id="address">
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="submit" value="Register" class="registerbutton" name="register" onSubmit="validate()">
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </form>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</body>
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: my assignment tells me to create a validation for the form, I have to make sure all the fields are filled in, if not It should display an error message!

Comment: Error: cannot read content of question

Comment: It should be `var firstName = document.getElmenetById('firstName').value;`

Comment: You should paste your actual code inside the post instead of images. Image is used for explaining a problem regarding interface. And include an explanation of the problem

Comment: I added code.. but my indentation is so bad it won't accept it XD, and I did first_Name. it works now. but now even tho I fill first name field, it still says Enter First name!

Comment: If you don't know how to indent, use online beautifiers, as this: http://jsbeautifier.org/. But never post code as image, because people here won't even have a look at it. I mean, I won't.

Comment: @Mohammed, You are checking the length of lastName in the if loop of firstName

Comment: You really should paste your actual code inside the post because ppl will find it hard to help you as they have to write your code from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

You should use document.getElementsByName if you want to fetch the value using name attribute. I would recommend to do it by "id" attribute.

```
function submitFunction() {
        var firstName = document.getElementsByName("first_Name")[0].value;
         if (firstName == "" || firstName == null || firstName.length == 0) {
            alert("First Name is required");
            return false;
        } 
    }
```

Also add **return** to the onsubmit event to avoid page refresh.

```
<form name="Register" onsubmit="return submitFunction() " method="post">
```

Option 2 : Using HTML5

The **required** attribute will do the validation check and you can skip javascript.

```
<input type="text" name="first_Name" required>
```